# Put document contents in a textBox

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking to get the contents of a Google word document and put it in a textBox.  The following code is spitting out an error:

```
function listBoxClick(e) {
  var tapp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var docName = DocsList.find(e.parameter.doclist); //find the document with the same name as what the user clicked on
  var docContents = docName[0].getContentAsString(); //get contents of document
  tapp.getElementById("songboxID").setValue(songfile2); //set the value of the textBox to the contents of the document
  return tapp;
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
Unsupported conversion requested.
```

I read somewhere that we can't do this for Google Documents but we can for other non-google documents that we upload.  Is that right?

---

Here's the answer that I can't post for 5 more hours since I'm new and have no reputation:

With Serge's assistance, here's what worked for me:

```
function listBoxClick(e) {
  var tapp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var docName = DocsList.find(e.parameter.doclist); //get document name based on what user clicked on in listBox
  var docId = docName[0].getId(); //get document ID
  var content = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getText(); //get contents of document
  tapp.getElementById("songboxID").setValue(content); //set web app's textBox (called songboxID) to match the contents of the document the user clicked on
  return tapp;
}
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, I uploaded a generic ini file from my computer and I'm able to see the contents of that just fine.  I've also tried .getAs(), but if that's the way to do it, I don't know what I'm suppose to be setting it as (I've tried application/vnd.google-apps.document to no avail).

Comment: Just to give an idea of what's going on, web page has three columns.  Left column is a listBox (non-drop-down), middle column is a textArea, right column is currently unused.  Left column gets populated with the user's documents in a certain folder (having the folder created is currently a pre-req for this, I'm sure I can code something later).  When the user clicks on any of those, the document's contents gets added to the center column for editing and what-not.  I guess you could say right now it's just a GUI for documents, but I'll be doing other stuff later to the center column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `DocumentApp.getText();` to get the text content of your document.

in you code it would become :

```
function listBoxClick(e) {
  var tapp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Logger.log(e.parameter.doclist)
  var docName = DocsList.find(e.parameter.doclist); //find the document with the same name as what the user clicked on
  var docId = docName[0].getId();
  Logger.log(docName[0].getName()+' = '+docId)
  var textContent = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getText();
  Logger.log(textContent)
  tapp.getElementById("songboxID").setValue(textContent); //set the value of the textBox to the contents of the document
  return tapp;
}
```

---

**EDIT :** as you noticed with your experiments `DocsList.find(e.parameter.doclist)` returns results that you didn't expect... that's simply because the `find` operator searches not only on doc's names but also on docs content.

To solve that , you should add a smal routine that checks the results of the find query against the documents name, something like this :

```
var docName = DocsList.find(e.parameter.doclist); //find the document with the same name as what the user clicked on

      for(var d in docName){{
         if(docName[d].getName()==e.parameter.doclist){
         var docId = docName[d].getId();
        }
      }
```

This will ensure that the document you are looking for is actually the right one.

PS: sorry for not having mentioned that immediately... it just slipped out of my mind ;-)

Comment: I was sure this was it, but every time I try I get "Error encountered: Document is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)"  Even when I put the ID in (as opposed to docID).  Do you know why that's happening?

Comment: OK... I got this to sort of work.  If I created a spanking new document it works (got the idea from here https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1438#c8).
Problem now is that it's not grabbing the entirety of the document.

Comment: *Sigh* and now suddenly it's working on documents it wasn't previously... I wonder if Google is doing something.  Although I'm still having issues with getting the entirety of the document.

Comment: I added a few logs in the code so you can see what happens and where/why it fails or not.

Comment: Sorry to add all these comments (but I feel like I should as opposed to editing previous comments), now it's not working.  I didn't make any changes, there's definitely something wonky going on.  I am trying to deploy this as a web app and I run into these problems when I click the "Test web app for you latest code" link.  Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: what do you get in the logger ? what type of widget is songboxID ?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm a newbie coder here (I was on the CS track in college, but that was 14 years ago).  I wasn't familiar with the logger at all, let me try that.

Comment: No problems... I edited the logs, there were some typos . Now it should show you useful info.

Comment: Ah... well, now things work fully (all text of the document), but not on every document.  However, using your logs (I was wondering where I could put "watches" in, thanks) I was able to determine that when it fails, it also pulls different document name that what was clicked on in the listBox.

Comment: OK, so it doesn't open anything that's not a Google Document, which I think is just what I need for now.  As far as I can tell I think I have it.

Comment: glad to hear that... indeed you can only use this method on Google Documents. please consider to accept the answer if you think it deserves it.